# Is there a way to make width as height?

Tags: css

I have styles like this and I want to make width of div same as height,
how can I implement It

```html
<main>
<span>1234567890</span>
<div></div>
</main>
<style>
main{
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
}
div{
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}</style>
```

Currently example is not working and width is 0

Comment: *and width is 0* --> because height is also 0

Comment: but I want width of div to be same as height of text))
Is it possible without js

Comment: If there is nothing in a `div`, it will by default have 0 height/width. `height: fit-content` and `aspect-ratio: 1` does nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with CSS grid but the green rectangle will overflow the container:

```css
main {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

div {
  background: green;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks it works but when I'm trying to change the scale, width of square does not revert back after decreasing scale, is it possible to bypass this problem?

Comment: @Serio refresh the page, it might be a bug

Answer (score 1):

You can use `1em` as width & height for your div if you know your text is only 1 line:

```html
<main>
  <span>1234567890</span>
  <div></div>
</main>

<style>
  main{
    position: relative;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
  }

  div {
    background: green;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
  }
</style>
```